# how to append the key values in python

Tags: python-2.7

i have the data in the .json file in the following format

```
[
    {
        "FIRSTNAME":"NAOMI","EMAIL":"HJHU@hiuj.com","ADDLINE":"jnjn","CITY":"hbiu",
        "FIRSTNAME":"gsf","EMAIL":"ghjujk@hn.com","ADDLINE":"kfjm","CITY":"hjhdjdyh",
        "FIRSTNAME":"sgbg","EMAIL":"aeth@aeth.com","ADDLINE":"dzfht","CITY":"sbfbg",
        "FIRSTNAME":"jkju","EMAIL":"ethe@th.com","ADDLINE":"tdhat","CITY":"dfhbdth",
    }
]
```

I want CITY to be appended to ADDLINE, renamed as ADDRESS and updated in a .csv file.
The output should be

```
[
    {
        "FIRST NAME":"NAOMI","EMAIL":"HJHU@hiuj.com","ADDRESS":"jnjn,hbiu",
        "FIRST NAME":"gsf","EMAIL":"ghjujk@hn.com","ADDRESS":"kfjm,hjhdjdyh",
        "FIRST NAME":"sgbg","EMAIL":"aeth@aeth.com","ADDRESS":"dzfht,sbfbg",
        "FIRST NAME":"jkju","EMAIL":"ethe@th.com","ADDRESS":"tdhat,dfhbdth",
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what you would like to do?

Comment: Pls format your code

Comment: It neither a valid json file nor csv file.

Comment: i want to append CITY with ADDLINE and rename it as ADDRESS.

Comment: it is a valid json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of the JSON library in Python's homepage: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

You need to load the json file:

```
data=json.loads(file('json.json').read())
```

and then process the data:

```
for row in data:
  row['ADDRESS'] = row['ADDRESS']+','+row['CITY']
  del row['CITY']
```

...and then write it back to a file:

```
file('json2.json','w').write(json.dumps(data))
```

Of course, in your final solution be sure to close the files you've opened.

By the way, your example is not a valid JSON file, and the output you provided looks more like JSON than CSV although it's not valid JSON either. So, I assumed you want the output as JSON.

If you really want the output as CSV, read https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

```
source_file = open('source.json', 'r')
output_file = open('output.csv', 'w')

for line in source_file:
    item = json.loads(line.strip())
    item['ADDRESS'] = "%s,%s" % (item['ADDRESS'], item['CITY'])
    del item['CITY']
    output_file.write(','.join(item.values()) + '\n')

source_file.close()
output_file.close()
```